# How to add a right-click extension/menu

Tags: c#, windows, text

Is it possible to install a right-click extension when in windows file browser, coded in C#?

I will take Winrar as an example:

When in the file browser, you can right click a file and Winrar will be in the list, giving a few options like "Unrar" "extract here" etc.

Is it possible to code the same thing, but when the user right clicks a file, to show my own app in the list, giving two options:

```
Open with -Myapphere-
Open with -Myapphere- text editor
```

The first option should start-up my application, and then run the file, being instructioned by the contents IN the file (start, pause etc)
The second option should open the file in my app's editor, DISPLAYING the contents of the file.

I already know how I am going to run / edit it, but how would I let my app now that it has to edit / run the file?

1. How would I install the right-click extension using the c# installer?
2. And then how would I open my app and the file with it, when clicked in the explorer?
3. And how would I make my program notice it is launched from a browser file?

Comment: This can be done using the registry, following link will help you : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: @Max I already saw that link, but how would I code it in the C# installer so that it would install for any user, and how would I add multiple options etc. ?

Comment: My next guess, would be to insert something in the registry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx you should insert the key, exactly as in the previous link, but modify it for your application name.

Comment: Is it possible to insert that key inside c#? I just don't understand how to insert it using an installer.. Note that I want every user to be able to have it, by just installing my app.

Comment: You could insert following code, in start of your application, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close(); Just modify the values to your application and a key will be inserted.

Comment: @Bart, Which Installer are you using? Are you using "Installation shield limited edition"(comes with VS 2010 and 2012 and 2013)? or, are you using free installer which comes with(VS 2008 and 2010)?